# Multiple generic types in class

Tags: c++

I have these structs

```
typedef struct {
 int a;
} a;
typedef struct {
 char a;
} aa;
typedef struct {
 short b;
} b;
typedef struct {
 char b;
} bb;

class Test {
private:
 a i; //or b i;
 aa c; // or bb c;
}
```

I want to create a class that will have the same code, and use `a,aa` structs or `b,bb` structs depending on the declaration of the class, I don't want to template each function in the class separately, and I want the class to know which set of structs to before the constructor is called or in the constructor,How to do that? Thanks.

Comment: You also don't want to make the whole class a `template <bool>`?

Comment: Is turning the class into a class template an option?

Comment: yes its fine to turn the class to template

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I quite understand the question, but are you looking for something like this, by any chance?

```
#include <type_traits>

template <bool UseA>
class Test {
private:
 typename std::conditional<UseA, a, b>::type i;
 typename std::conditional<UseA, aa, bb>::type c;
};

Test<true> test_using_a;
Test<false> test_using_b;
```

Answer (score 0):

A general solution for having two members of varying types is of course:

```
template<class X, class Y>
class Test {
private:
   X i;
   Y c;
};
```

Then you can instantiate any combinations you want, like `Test<a,aa>`, `Test<b,bb>`, or even go crazy with `Test<b,aa>`.